# Kendo UI TreeView - how to copy contents from one treeview to another?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have two Kendo UI TreeViews on one page.  For example:

```
var data1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        { text: "foo", items: [
            { text: "believe" },
            { text: "Sofas" },
            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
        ] },
        { text: "Decor", items: [
            { text: "Bed Linen" },
            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
            { text: "Carpets" }
        ] }
    ]
});

var data2 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [

    ]
});


$("#treeview-1").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: data1
}); 

$("#treeview-2").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: data2
});

$('#copy-button').click(function(e){
  // what goes here?
});
```

How can I copy the data from one tree to the other?  It's OK if the destination tree's existing data is overwritten.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the data of the first tree and assign it to the DataSource of the second. Something like:

```
// Access both trees
var tree1 = $("#treeview-1").data("kendoTreeView");
var tree2 = $("#treeview-2").data("kendoTreeView");
// Get the data from the first tree
var data = tree1.dataSource.data();
// Assign it to the second tree
tree2.dataSource.data(data);
```

A snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
      { text: "foo", items: [
        { text: "believe" },
        { text: "Sofas" },
        { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
      ] },
      { text: "Decor", items: [
        { text: "Bed Linen" },
        { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
        { text: "Carpets" }
      ] }
    ]
  });

  var data2 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [

    ]
  });


  $("#treeview-1").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: data1
  }); 

  $("#treeview-2").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: data2
  });

  $('#copy-button').click(function(e){
    var tree1 = $("#treeview-1").data("kendoTreeView");
    var tree2 = $("#treeview-2").data("kendoTreeView");
    var data = tree1.dataSource.data();
    tree2.dataSource.data(data)
  });
});
```

```css
#treeview-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 40px;
}

#treeview-2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="copy-button" class="k-button">Copy</button>
<div id="treeview-1"></div>
<div id="treeview-2"></div>
```